Data smoothing with controlled smoothing error
Say I have a data sets $X$ and $T$ of $n$ measurements at $n$ distinct times. The data is slow varying and relatively non-noisy. I want to smooth the data with some curve or a set of piecewise continuous curves. I want a method (algorithm) which could guarantee the following.

$O(n)$ complexity
A way to analytically (or at least with very little iterative overhead, so that condition 1 is still guaranteed) control the error of the smoothed data. Say if there is some smoothing parameter $p$ resulting in smoothed curve $X'$, then I need to find a way to select $p(\epsilon)$ in such a way that $ |X'(t_i)- X(t_i)|<\epsilon \quad \forall i\leq n $
At least $C^2$ continuity would be amazing, but non essential.

I was looking into sliding windows techniques (which so far for me seems the best), splines, but all seem to resort to fit the curve, check the error, readjust smoothing parameter. As the data set can approach  10s of millions of elements, I need something faster.
Any help, recommendations, links to interesting articles would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much!
